# Firebase: update database when no write operation happens in 5 minutes interval

Tags: angular, firebase

I would like to write a database rule where I need to update a specific record's key when no write operation occurs for that record.

Scenario: A collaborative notepad where multiple user be able to update the text. When one user starts writing it is locked for others by enabling `lock: true`. So other won't be able to update until the lock is released. If a user starts writing and is away for a longer time or closes the app the state of that note is always `lock: true` which will never let others to update! How do I overcome this situation?

Is it possible to use database rules to change the state to `lock: false` if there is not write operation for 5 minutes? Or should I handle this in the application itself

Comment: So what you've presented here is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Essentially, you've decided the solution is using `lock: true` and instead of asking for solutions to the problem, asked for solutions to the solution. The answers here will miss the mark since the best answer is probably just to lock on the timestamp and write security rules to prevent write for 5m based on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible to use database rules to change the state to lock: false if there aren't any write operations for 5 minutes? No.

**Here's what you can do.** (I'm addressing the rules option first because that's what your question is aimed at, but the second option might be a better fit. Your choice.)

Assuming your db structure looks a little bit like this;

```
root: {
  notes: {
    $note: {
      locked: true,
      lockedBy: uid,
      lockedOn: 1489181073472  // Time in milliseconds since UNIX epoch
    }
  }
}
```

You could use the database rules below to allow other users to **overwrite** a note's data if the lock has been on for longer than 5 minutes. Basically, this will simply ignore the `locked: true`. The downside to that is that if you have any listeners that are listening for a `false` value, well, they won't be called.

```
{
"rules": {
    "notes": {
      "$note": {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write": "data.child('lockedBy').val() === auth.uid || data.child('lock').val() === false || (data.child('lockedOn').val() + 300000) < now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step by step: what do these rules do (the write ones, the read one is pretty self explanatory):

This rule allows the person which placed to lock to always be able to write:

```
data.child('lockedBy').val() === auth.uid
```

This rule ensures people can write if lock is false:

```
data.child('lock').val() === false
```

And the last one makes sure that people can write if lockedOn is at least 5 minutes old.

```
(data.child('lockedOn').val() + 300000) < now
```

You'd obviously want to add some more rules to make sure the users are authenticated and so forth, but that falls outside of the scope of the question.

**Still,** none of this actually does what you wanted. If you want to be able to detect whether a lock has been on for more than 5 minutes, and then remove that lock. Well then you're in luck since the Firebase team just (yesterday, what timing) released the beta of **Cloud Functions for Firebase** and it just happens to be perfect for what you wanted. Basically, Functions provides you with a Node.js environment where you can run functions much like the client sided code, only on a server. You could write a function that monitors all notes that are currently locked, and make sure they haven't been locked for longer than 5 minutes. If they are you can update them. This will allow you to do what you wanted without having to do it client side.

Links:

[Introducing Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/introducing-cloud-functions-for-firebase.html)

[Functions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: This is a fair answer, but the presence of the `lock` boolean is entirely superfluous. Clients and security rules can both lock solely based on the timestamp with less complexity and better results.

Comment: Pieter thank you for the good answer! Cloud functions looks very promising as they perform operations like cron jobs. But atm I am using angularfire2 plugin so I have to wait until there is an update. For me the best option is using the database rules. Accepting this answer as I have solved my issue by making changes in the application :)